# For iOS APP, Show custom snapshot when move APP from background to foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Background:**

Our app will need to work like below:

1. Manually move APP foreground => background (Timing1)=>(Timing2)foreground

   - Timing1:iOS will take snapshot
   - Timing2:iOS will show snapshot
2. Automatically  move APP foreground (Timing3)=>(Timing4) background =>foreground

**Problem:**

At Timing4 iOS show snapshot taken at Timing1 instead of Timing3.

**Analyse:**

I think it is because at 2 situation our App moved automatically by other APP.So iOS do not have enough time to take snapshot at timing3 after "applicationdidenterbackground" method returned.

**Question:**

I want to force iOS to take snapshot which will be used for timing4.
SO

1. How can I force iOS use the snapshot I take instead the one iOS take by itself
2. At which step I should input code to release the function at 1.

Thanks.

Comment: Some information  I find https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html

Comment: Some information  I find https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW27  Please search for snapshot , I tried to add "snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:" at applicationDidEnterBackground, but it does not work.

Comment: Sorry the question has some problem , at 2  timing3 and timing4 are in wrong position. The correct one is as below Automatically move APP foreground =>(Timing3) background =>(Timing4)foreground